# 100 meters head start for the turtle, would the rabbit...

Tags: sequences-and-series

A rabbit challenged a turtle to a racing match and the turtle accepted it. The rabbit knows its advantages so he let the turtle go with a 100 meters head start, the rabbit is 10 times faster than the turtle.Can the rabbit catch up? Who will win?
Turtle = 1 meter per second
Rabbit = 10 meters per second

Comment: If the track is 101m long, the rabbit loses. If the track is 101km long, the rabbit wins.

Comment: Thank you I really apprecriate that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that wasn't an answer. I was just observing that the problem is missing the length of the track.

Comment: "Can the rabbit catch up" sounds like an invitation to a paradox; see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/142932/139123

Comment: Our proffesor didn't even gave us how long the track is, he said we can answer this wihout a length of the track.

Comment: Then based on what you have here, you should be able to explain clearly to your professor why you don't have enough information.  Maybe he didn't state the problem as intended, maybe the fact that it is not soluble is the desired answer.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli - very nice illustration, esp the use of 101m and 101km :)

Answer (score 2):

After $x$ seconds,
the turtle will have gone
$x+100$ meters,
and the hare will have gone
$10x$ meters.

From this,
you can figure out
when they will have travelled
the same distance.
The turtle will be ahead
before then,
and the hare will be ahead
after then.

The result depends
on the length of the race,
which you did not state.

Comment: Our proffesor didn't even gave us how long the track is, he said we can answer this wihout a length of the track.

Comment: As I said, work out where the two will tie.