# Is there anything else than a $\sigma$-algebra or is $\sigma$-algebra the only meaningful algebra on sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there anything else than a $\sigma$-algebra or is $\sigma$-algebra the only meaningful algebra on sets?

It seems that the $\sigma$-algebra has been invented in order to serve some particular higher level constructs, but I wonder if there are some other useful algebras on sets?

Comment: Regarding your first comment yes. $\sigma$-algebras are very useful in measure theory. Namely, measures are defined over $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: (Non countable) algebras are useful constructs in many senses. Generally they form the stage for anything involving (finite) unions and complementation.

Comment: [**Boolean Algebras**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0000BNXRD) by Roman Sikorski discusses algebras in which "countable" is replaced by various cardinal numbers (not necessarily the same for intersections and unions). See also [Is there a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ strictly between the Borel and Lebesgue algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142381/is-there-a-sigma-algebra-on-mathbbr-strictly-between-the-borel-and-lebes) and papers such as [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm136/fm136118.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

By [Stone's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) for Boolean algebras, the theory of algebras on sets coincides essentially with the theory of Boolean algebras in general. As such, general algebras of sets are extremely useful.