# Showing a set is Borel and a function is Borel measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

I am stuck in the following question:

Suppose $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function. Let $g(x)=\begin{cases}
 f(x), & \text{if } x \in B,\\
 0,    & \text{if } x \in B^c
\end{cases}$.

I would like to first show that $B$ is a Borel set and that the function $g$ is Borel measurable. I know the required definitions, but I can't figure out how to put things together to solve this. Would someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the definition of a Borel measurable function is that the preimages of Borel sets are Borel. $\mathbb{R}$ is a very Borelly Borel set, so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = B$ is Borel as well. Simple as that!

Again to show that $g$ is Borel you need to show that $g^{-1}(A)$ is Borel for every Borel $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But notice we may divide this into two cases: if $0 \in A$, then $g^{-1}(A) = B^{c} \cup f^{-1}(A)$. Both of these are Borel since, again $f$ is Borel measurable and $B^{c}$ is Borel as $B$ is (sigma algebras are closed under complements). And otherwise if $0 \not \in A$, then $g^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A)$ which is again Borel as $f$ is Borel measurable. Thus the $g$ preimages of borel sets are Borel, meaning $g$ is Borel.

Comment: (+1) for "$\mathbb{R}$ is a very Borelly Borel set" I might have used your expression in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007632/is-there-a-mathematical-way-to-measure-complexity#comment8290165_4007632) if I had seen it  a few weeks ago!

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is a borel set because we may take $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=B$.

As for $g$, we see that $g^{-1}(0)$ is the complement of $B$ which must be a borel set since our borel sigma algebra is closed under complement. $g$ behaves as $f$ otherwise which implies it is borel measurable.