# Let on $\mathbb{R}^n$ be $\mathcal{L}$ - Lebesgue measurable sets, and $\mathcal{B}$ - Borel measurable sets. Why not $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{B}$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

It appears to me, at least because we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that they should be the same, and not - how we've been told in our lecture - that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

I mean, what should you do differently here? Sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are Borel measurable are from the sigma algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are of the form $(a_1, b_1) \times ... \times (a_n, b_n)$

So what difference does it make whether I choose a set from $\mathcal{L}$ or $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: Well simply because there are sets is $\mathcal L$ that are not in $\mathcal B$, see this for example: https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2021/fs/401-2284-00L/sc/notes_exclass04.pdf

Comment: There are some posts on this site about sets which are Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable: [Lebesgue measurable set that is not a Borel measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141017). Also cardinality argument could be used: [Cardinality of Borel sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70880).

Comment: That's clear, but I am talking specifically about sets on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do you maybe know an example for that? Or is that example on the Cantor set the example I'm looking for?

Comment: The Lebesgue sigma algebra is obtained completing the Borrel one. Take any non Borrel set which is contained in a Lebesgue (measure) negligible set.

Comment: "Take any non Borrel set which is contained in a Lebesgue (measure) negligible set." Yes, but like what for example? That's my question basically, I want to know which set (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is Lebesgue measurable, but not Borel measurable

Comment: miguelsxvi generously gave you an exemple for $n = 1$. It means he offered you $A \subset \mathbb R$ not Borel such that there exists $N \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R) $ with $A \subset N$ and $\lambda(N) = 0$. If you want an example in dimension $n$ considere $A^n$ and use the definition of the product measure.

Comment: Of strong related interest is [Is there a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ strictly between the Borel and Lebesgue algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/142381/13130) and [this 5 June 2001 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/3rOWa0EdBcA/m/cxDrannspYIJ). Regarding “explicit natural examples”, the following from the lower fourth of p. 756 of [*Continuity and Baire functions*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318011) by Lorch (1971) indicates the situation at even almost the very beginning of the Borel hierarchy: “$\ldots$ the reader is reminded of the fact **(continued)**

Comment: that sets which are of type $F_{\sigma \delta \sigma}$ or $G_{\delta \sigma \delta}$ and not of lower type—with respect to any of the classic topologies—are very thinly scattered through the literature. In fact, looking for them is almost like hunting for unicorns.”

Comment: @blamethelag My tab in my browser crashes all the time if I try to open the link miguelsxvi sent me, and I also cannot download that PDF, too