# Sets that are divisible by 2 without the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I define a non-empty set $S$ to be divisible by $2$ if it can be partitioned into two sets $\{A,B\}$ such that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality. I also define a non-empty set $S$ to be pair-partitionable if it can be partitioned into a partition that consist exclusively of unordered pairs. I have some questions regarding these definitions.

1. Without the axiom of choice, can any infinite set be divided by $2$?
2. Without the axiom of choice, is every infinite set pair-partitionable?
3. Now, my main question. Without the axiom of choice, for every infinite set $S$, is being divisible by $2$ an equivalent property of being pair-partitionable?

Comment: The answer to all three questions is negative. In particular, an **amorphous** set can never be divided by 2, but it is consistent that there are amorphous pair-partitionable sets. See [this old answer of Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60285/28111) and the cited references (I'm not sure this is quite a duplicate, but I'm sure this question has been asked here before).

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/69461/7206